# Java arrays code in max and min

Tags: java, arrays, max, average, min

My project is about finding the average, minimum and maximum of students' grades and their standing, but it keeps showing me an error on the output.

---

Here are the names and the grades:

Students:

```
Alia Nahid Eiman Suad Lamia Salma Mai Wedad Haya Sanaa
```

Quiz:

```
10 20 50 70 80 50 30 90 60 40
```

Midterm:

```
30 80 100 40 80 70 70 80 50 30
```

Final Exam:

```
40 80 70 100 90 60 70 50 40 80
```

---

And here is the Java code:

```
package java_final_project;

import java.util.*;

public class Java_Final_Project {
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare inputs:
        String letter1, letter2, letter3;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // Declare the four array structures
        int[] quiz = new int[10];
        int[] midterm = new int[10];
        int[] finalexam = new int[10];
        String[] students = new String[10];  

        // Input elements to the arrays
        int counter, sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        int sum3 = 0;
        double ave1, ave2, ave3;
        int max1, max2, max3;
        int min1, min2, min3;

        for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
            System.out.println ("Enter student names and grades of quiz, midterm "
                + "and final with space between them");
            students[counter] = console.next();
            quiz[counter] = console.nextInt();
            sum1 = sum1 + quiz[counter];
            midterm[counter]= console.nextInt();
            sum2 = sum2 + midterm[counter];
            finalexam[counter]= console.nextInt();
            sum3 = sum3 + finalexam[counter];
        }

        ave1 = sum1 / 10;
        ave2 = sum2 / 10;
        ave3 = sum3 / 10;

        // min and max values
        max1 = Math.max(quiz[counter], max);
        max2 = Math.max(midterm[counter], max);
        max3 = Math.max(finalexam[counter], max);

        min1 = Math.min(quiz[counter], min);
        min2 = Math.min(midterm[counter], min);
        min3 = Math.min(finalexam[counter], min);

        // if statement for the standing
        // ave1
        if (ave1 >= 90 && ave1 <= 100) {
            letter1 = "E";
        } else if (ave1 >= 70 && ave1 <= 80) {
            letter1 = "G";
        } else if (ave1 >= 50 && ave1 <= 60) {
            letter1 = "S";
        } else {
            letter1 = "P";
        }

        // ave2
        if (ave2 >= 90 && ave2 <= 100) {
            letter2 = "E";
        } else if (ave2 >= 70 && ave2 <= 80) {
            letter2 = "G";
        } else if (ave2 >= 50 && ave2 <= 60) {
            letter2 = "S";
        } else {
            letter2 = "P";
        }

        //ave3
        if (ave3 >= 90 && ave3 <= 100) {
            letter3 = "E";
        } else if (ave3 >= 70 && ave3 <= 80) {
            letter3 = "G";
        } else if (ave3 >= 50 && ave3 <= 60) {
            letter3 = "S";
        } else {
            letter3 = "P";
        }

        // Display the elements of the four arrays  
        System.out.println("Here is the elements of the four arrays");
        System.out.println("students" + "\t" + "quiz" + "\t" + "midterm" + "\t" + "finalexam");
        for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
            System.out.println(students[counter] + "\t" + quiz[counter] + "\t" + midterm[counter] + "\t" + finalexam[counter]);
        }
        System.out.println("Summary Report:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("students" + "\t" + "\t" + "Quiz" + "\t" + "\t" + "Midterm" + "\t" + "\t" + "FinalExam");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Average" + "\t" + "\t" + ave1 + "\t" + "\t" + ave2 + "\t" + "\t" + ave3);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Max" + "\t" + "\t" + max1 + "\t" + "\t" + max2 + "\t" + "\t" + max3);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Min" + "\t" + "\t" + min1 + "\t" + "\t" + min2 + "\t" + "\t" + min3);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Standing" + "\t" + "\t" + letter1 + "\t" + "\t" + letter2 + "\t" + "\t" + letter3);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't tell us what the error is, it's very hard to help you find it.

Comment: Try this. Initialize max1, max2 and max3 to the  integer value. And then:                  max1 = Math.max(quiz[counter], max1);     max2 = Math.max(midterm[counter], max2);     max3 = Math.max(finalexam[counter], max3);

Comment: You should cast this to double                                           ave1 = sum1/10;
ave2 = sum2/10;
ave3 = sum3/10;

Comment: The thing you're calling "standing" seems to be calculated in a very strange way.  What is this actually supposed to mean?

Comment: it shows me that their is an error in max1 , 2 and 3 @DavidWallace

Comment: the standing is the alphabetical grade. E is Excellent G is good S is satisfying and P is poor @DavidWallace

Comment: Yes.  And by not telling us what the error is, you've made it far more difficult for anyone to give you a good answer.  Don't just say "there is an error in max1, 2 and 3".  WHAT IS THE ERROR?  However, now that it's more than 12 hours since you asked the question, you're unlikely to get anyone new coming along to help you.

Comment: And your calculation of "standing" makes no sense.  You're using the average across the whole class to calculate it?  Don't you intend to have a standing for each person?  And why do you give a standing of P for a grade of 85 or 65, but other standings for lower scores?

Comment: this should be in the Summary Report: min quiz 20 midterm 30 final 50, max 100 , 80 , 100 ave 50.9, 40.6, 70.9 standing S , P , G @DavidWallace

Comment: this is what the output gives me: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at java_final_project.Java_Final_Project.main(Java_Final_Project.java:66) Java Result: 1 @DavidWallace

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ... as I thought. Read David Wallaces answer (and my comment under it) solve that.

Answer (score 0):

The six lines where you set `min1, min2, min3, max1, max2, max3` need to be up, inside the `for` loop where you gather the input; because you want to check after each input whether it's bigger or smaller than the current maximum and minimum.  Where you have those lines at the moment, they can't possible work, because `counter` is no longer pointing to an entry in the array.

Comment: `because there is no such variable as counter` yes there is. `counter` is declared outside of that `for` loop and will have the value `10` at the above mentioned lines. That likely causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Tom - OK, thanks, I didn't spot that.  For some reason I thought he/she had declared it in the for loop.  I'll fix it up.

Comment: I guess because that is the proper way? :D The usage of `counter` outside of the loop causes some problems for him.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are allowed to use streams in your assignment. If you are then there is a much easier way of getting min, max, average in Java 8:

```
int[] scores = {1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 2};
int max = Arrays.stream(scores).max();
int min = Arrays.stream(scores).min();
int avg = Arrays.stream(scores).average();
```

You don't really need to use loops often now that Java has streams.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the codes and corrected some mistakes. Here's the updated java code and it worked :D! and I thank you for your comments and help :)

```
package java_final_project;



import java.util.*;

public class Java_Final_Project



{

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)



{
    // Declare inputs:
    String letter1, letter2, letter3;
    double ave1, ave2, ave3;

    // Declare the four array structures
    int[] quiz = new int[10];
    int[] midterm = new int[10];
    int[] finalexam = new int[10];
    String [] students = new String[10]; 
    int [] scores = new int[100]; 

    // Input elements to the arrays
    int counter, sum1=0;
    int sum2=0;
    int sum3=0;

    for ( counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
    System.out.println ("Enter student names and grades of quiz, midterm "
    + "and final with space between them");

    students[counter] = console.next();
    quiz[counter]= console.nextInt();
    sum1 = sum1 + quiz[counter];
    midterm[counter]= console.nextInt();
    sum2 = sum2 + midterm[counter];
    finalexam[counter]= console.nextInt();
    sum3 = sum3 + finalexam[counter];                     
    }

    // max and min values for the quiz
    int minGrade = quiz[0];
    int maxGrade = quiz[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
if (minGrade > quiz[i])
  minGrade = quiz[i];
if (maxGrade < quiz[i])
  maxGrade = quiz[i];
}

// max and min values for the midterm
int minGrade1 = midterm[0];
int maxGrade1 = midterm[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { if (minGrade1 > midterm[i])
  minGrade1 = midterm[i];
if (maxGrade1 < midterm[i])
  maxGrade1 = midterm[i];}

// max and min values for the final
int minGrade2 = finalexam[0];
int maxGrade2 = finalexam[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{if (minGrade2 > finalexam[i])
  minGrade2 = finalexam[i];
if (maxGrade2 < finalexam[i])
  maxGrade2 = finalexam[i];}

    //calculate the average of quiz, midterm, final        
    ave1 = sum1/10;
    ave2 = sum2/10;
    ave3 = sum3/10;

    // if statement for the standing
    // ave1
        if (ave1 > 90 && ave1 > 100)
        {letter1 = "E";}
       else if (ave1 > 70 && ave1 > 80)
        {letter1 = "G" ;}
       else if (ave1 > 50 && ave1 > 60)
        {letter1 = "S";}
       else 
       {letter1 = "P";}

    // ave2
       if (ave2 > 90 && ave2 > 100)
        {letter2 = "E";}
       else if (ave2 > 70 && ave2 > 80)
        {letter2 = "G" ;}
       else if (ave2 > 50 && ave2 > 60)
        {letter2 = "S";}
       else 
       {letter2 = "P";}

    //ave3
       if (ave3 > 90 && ave3 > 100)
        {letter3 = "E";}
       else if (ave3 > 70 && ave3 > 80)
        {letter3 = "G" ;}
       else if (ave3 > 50 && ave3 > 60)
        {letter3 = "S";}
       else 
       {letter3 = "P";}

   // Display the elements of the four arrays  
    System.out.println (" Here is the elements of the four arrays");
    System.out.println ("students"+"\t"+"quiz"+"\t"+"\t"+"midterm"+"\t"+"\t"+"finalexam");
    for ( counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {

    System.out.println (students[counter]+"\t"+"\t"+quiz[counter]+"\t"+"\t"+midterm[counter]
            +"\t"+"\t"+finalexam[counter]);

    }

     System.out.println ("  ");
     System.out.println ("Summary Report:");
     System.out.println ("\t"+"\t"+"Quiz"+"\t"+"\t"+"Midterm"+"\t"+"\t"+"FinalExam");
     System.out.println ("Average"+"\t"+"\t"+ave1+"\t"+"\t"+ave2+"\t"+"\t"+ave3);
     System.out.println ("max"+ "\t"+"\t"+maxGrade+ "\t"+"\t"+ maxGrade1+ "\t"+"\t"+ maxGrade2);
     System.out.println ("min"+ "\t"+"\t"+minGrade+ "\t"+"\t"+ minGrade1+ "\t"+"\t"+ minGrade2);
     System.out.println ();
     System.out.println ("Standing"+ "\t"+ letter1+ "\t"+ "\t"+ letter2+ "\t"+"\t"+ letter3);
}    
}
```